# Unable to edit a comment on a answer

Tags: support, comments, editing

I was going to make an edit to my comment on the below answer to a question as I feel I may have been a little terse with my response to it. When I went to edit...I can't, only delete. Are you still able to edit your comment on a answer or has this been removed?

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are still able to edit comments, they haven't changed.

The rules have always been the same as those for voting, you can only change a vote within X amount of time of it being made, you can also only edit a comment within a small amount of time of posting it.

Comment: Thanks mate, thought I had lost the plot :(..glad its nearly Friday!

Comment: The window for editing comments is 5 minutes.